# Access accelerometer from AndroidApplication (libGdx)

Tags: android, libgdx, accelerometer

I want to read the accelerometer values using the libGdx framework. If in the AndroidApliccation I set `config.useAccelerometer = true` and I try to read them within the AplicationAdapter, everything works. But If I try to read values straight in the AndroidApplication, it returns 0, and `Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Peripheral.Accelerometer)` returns false. Is there a way to fix this? Is there a way to use a similar command to "useAccelerometer" for a AndroidApplication? I need to access the accelerometer from the AndroidAplication itself.

Comment: Source please. Are you sure `config.useAccelerometer = true` is initialized before calling `isPeripheralAvailable`?

Comment: @HBizhi `config.useAccelerometer=true` is called in the AndroidApplication to set the ApplicationAdapter configuration. If I call ´isPeripheralAvailable´ on the ApplicationAdapter it returns true, if I call it in  the AndroidApplication it returns false. I need it to treturn true in the AndroidApplication.

Comment: I suspect this is because libgdx hasn't started running properly until it starts your ApplicationAdapter. Why do you need it in there anyway? As a general rule you shouldn't put anything in there unless you absolutely can't put it anywhere else.